# Longest common sublist

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

While trying to write a solution to the longest common sublist problem in Scheme, I'm having trouble figuring out what is wrong with what I have so far.  I think it's the right idea and before worrying about polynomial time I'm just trying to get one that works at all.  I haven't written in a functional language before and the syntactic differences can make things a little harder at first.

```
(define (lcs lst1 lst2)
(if (or (null? lst1) (null? lst2)) '()
      (if (not (null? lcs)) lcs
          (if (equal? (car lst1) (car lst2))
              (cons (car lst1))(lcs (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))
          (let ((a (lcs (cdr lst1) lst2))
                (b (lcs lst1 (cdr lst2))))
            (if (> (cadr a) (cadr b)) a b)))))
```

Is this on the right track?  What's wrong with it?
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: A typo, I had them all called that at first then changed it to just lcs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(if (not (null? lcs)) lcs
```

Here you're checking whether `lcs` (which is a function) is the empty list. If it isn't (which is always the case because a function is not a list), you return the function itself.

I assume what you meant to do was to call the function `lcs` and check whether the result was the empty list. To call a function, you need to surround the function in parentheses. Further if the function takes arguments (which `lcs` does), you need to specify those arguments when calling the function.

It is not clear to me what this `if` is supposed to accomplish and as far as I can tell, there's no need for it, so just remove it.

```
(if (> (cadr a) (cadr b)) a b)
```

`cadr` returns the second element of a list, so here you're returning the list whose second element is greater. Given that your goal is to find the longest sublist, this makes no sense. You should be returning the list whose length is greater. To do this replace the condition with

```
(> (length a) (length b))
```

In addition to those logic errors, you have a small syntax error:

```
(cons (car lst1)) (lcs (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))
```

Here you're calling `cons` with one argument (which is an error) and then calling `(lcs (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2))` as the else-part of the list. Since you obviously intended `(lcs (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2))` to be the second argument to `cons`, just remove the second closing paren after `car lst1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful.  The logic errors seemed obvious after your answer.

Comment: What is the runtime of this algorithm? Non-polynomial, correct?

Comment: @John: That's correct. Since in the worst case the function calls itself twice at every step (with a recursion depth of n) the runtime is exponential.